# How can I beforehand determine whether a material is a good candidate for a microwave sensor?

Tags: material-science, dielectric, microwaves

Is there a table of some sort or formula where I can determine before I test the material under a microwave sensor whether it will allow the microwaves to pass through and if so at what depth.

for instance Copper will work/ not work up to these depths / all depths.

Is there a table that will say between these parameters the material will work or not work and why.

and a formula to determine to what depth?

Don't know if there is more information needed in my question....

We have the equipment to test and make observations, but I want to be able when someone asks me about a material to make a prediction based on a table or formula that will tell me if the material will work or not and why then confirm with lab tests